# Change OIDC OWIN middleware within same Sitecore site

Tags: federated-authentication, owin, openid-connect

I have an OpenID Connect Identity Provider Processor for my Sitecore 9.0.1 site which is using federated authentication as described in Sitecore's [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/configure-federated-authentication.html#UUID-d19e2e29-ba2f-6382-82b3-b70d005023ef_id__Generate_sign-in_links). I'm also generating the sign-in links as per this documentation. This is currently working fine, however there is a change which requires us to use different `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` within the same site based on a certain condition. My plan was to use `App.MapWhen` with my conditions and specify the correct options inside each. However even using `App.MapWhen` with a single condition which is always true like this does not work:

```
protected override void ProcessCore([NotNull] IdentityProvidersArgs args)
{
    args.App.MapWhen(context => true, app =>
    {
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //my OIDC options
        });
     });
}
```

When I try to login now a 404 is thrown on the post from the login button to `/identity/externallogin`, this works fine without the `App.MapWhen` I understand Sitecore puts in middleware and what I'm doing might conflict with this. How do I use different OIDC options within the same site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the response from Sitecore support:

> According to the investigation performed, the `App.MapWhen` cannot be
> used in this method, since it implies direct interaction with OWIN
> middleware and bypasses federated authentication layer. Thus,
> implementation of your desired functionality would require a lot of
> customization and, unfortunately, falls out of scope of support.