# Sitecore 9.3 - Sitecore.Owin.Authentication - Unable to find "idp" claim in the identity

Tags: upgrade

I am working on upgrading a project from sitecore 8.1 to 9.3. I have added a new identity provider - AzureB2C to login into sites. It is using OpenIdConnect. I am able to navigate to the login page and get authenticated as well, but upon returning, I get blank error page -

[image]

It is redirecting to the redirectUrl configured and sends code, token and state as well. But after that this issue occurs. Below are the code and configs -

Config 1

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Project.SC.Feature.Login.Models.Routes.RegisterAuthRoutes, Project.SC.Feature.Login"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" resolve="true" />
      </initialize>
      <owin.identityProviders>
        <!--This is the custom processor that gets executed when azure AD posts the token to Sitecore-->
        <processor type="Project.SC.Feature.Login.Providers.AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor, Project.SC.Feature.Login" resolve="true" />
      </owin.identityProviders>
    </pipelines>
    <services>
     <!-- <configurator type= "Feature.AzureAdB2C.Models.AuthenticationConfigurator, Feature.AzureAdB2C"/>-->
      <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseAuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                lifetime="Singleton" />
      <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseTicketManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.TicketManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                lifetime="Singleton" />
      <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BasePreviewManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
                implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                lifetime="Singleton" />
    </services>
    <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <!--Provider mappings to sites-->
      <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
      </identityProvidersPerSites>

      <!--Definitions of providers-->
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider id="AzureAdB2C" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">AzureAdB2C</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>AzureAdB2C</caption>
          <domain>CustomDomainName</domain>
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
            <transformation name="nameClaimTransformation" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>

      <!--List of all shared transformations-->
      <sharedTransformations>
      </sharedTransformations>

      <!--Property mappings initializer-->
      <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      </propertyInitializer>

    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Config 2

```
<configuration> 
<sitecore>
<federatedAuthentication>
  <identityProvidersPerSites>
    <mapEntry name="portal" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>portal</site>
      </sites>
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='AzureAdB2C']"/>
      </identityProviders>
      <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
      </externalUserBuilder>
    </mapEntry>
  </identityProvidersPerSites>
</federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

IdentityProviderProcessor -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Project.SC.Feature.Login.Configuration;
using Project.SC.Feature.Login.Extensions;
using Project.SC.Feature.Login.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using Sitecore.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Extensions;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.IdentityProviders;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services;
using Sitecore.Text;
using Sitecore.Web;
using OpenIdConnectMessage = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage;

namespace Project.SC.Feature.Login.Providers
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public class AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor : IdentityProvidersProcessor
    {

        protected override string IdentityProviderName => "AzureAdB2C";

        public AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor(
            FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, ICookieManager cookieManager,
            BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            Log.Info("Inside AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> processcore ", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));
            List<SiteInfo> siteInfoList = Factory.GetSiteInfoList();
            IEnumerable<OpenIdConnectSiteInfo> sites =
                siteInfoList.Select(s => new OpenIdConnectSiteInfo(s)).Where(s => s.UsesOpenIdConnect);

            foreach (OpenIdConnectSiteInfo site in sites)
            {
                Log.Info("Inside foreach site in sites AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

                // NOTE [ILs] SXA allows adding multiple hostnames to be matched seperated by |
                foreach (string hostname in site.HostName.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    Log.Info("Inside foreach hostname in site.hostname AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

                    // args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromSiteInfo(site));
                    args.App.MapWhen(
                       ctx => ctx.MapDomain(hostname) && ctx.MapFolder(site.VirtualFolder),
                       app =>
                       {
                           CookieAuthentication.ConfigureCookieAuthentication(app);
                           app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromSiteInfo(site));
                       });

                    Log.Info("After MapWhen AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

                }
            }
        }

        private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromSiteInfo(OpenIdConnectSiteInfo site)
        {
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
            var identityProvider = GetIdentityProvider();
            Log.Info("Start AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> CreateOptionsFromSiteInfo ", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

            // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
            // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
            options.MetadataAddress = site.Authority;
            options.AuthenticationType = GetAuthenticationType();
            options.RedirectUri = site.RedirectUri;
            options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = site.PostlogoutRedirectUri;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = site.NameClaimType,
                SaveSigninToken = true
            };

            options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context => HandleOpenIdConnectAuthenticationFailed(context, site),
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context => HandleOpenIdConnectRedirectToIdentityProvider(context, site),
                //SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
                //{
                //    notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("idp", "azureadb2c"));

                //    // transform all claims
                //    ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                //    notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));

                //    return Task.CompletedTask;
                //}
            };

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            options.ClientId = site.ClientId;
            //http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest
            options.Scope = site.Scope;
            //http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.CodeIdToken;

            Log.Info("End AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> CreateOptionsFromSiteInfo", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

            return options;
        }

        /*
         *  On each call to Azure AD B2C, check if a policy (e.g. the profile edit or password reset policy) has been specified in the OWIN context.
         *  If so, use that policy when making the call. Also, don't request a code (since it won't be needed).
         */
        private static Task HandleOpenIdConnectRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification, OpenIdConnectSiteInfo site)
        {
            Log.Info("Start AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> HandleOpenIdConnectRedirectToIdentityProvider", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

            string policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(site.SignInPolicyId))
            {
                notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId;
                notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken;
                notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.Replace(site.SignInPolicyId, policy);
            }

            try
            {
                AddLanguageQueryString(notification);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.Message, ex, typeof(OpenIdConnectAuthentication));
            }

            Log.Info("End AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> HandleOpenIdConnectRedirectToIdentityProvider", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private static void AddLanguageQueryString(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            Log.Info("Start AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> AddLanguageQueryString", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

            string portalUrlCookie = "Project_portal";
            string langPrefCookieFormat = "Project_{0}#lang";
            string language = string.Empty;
            if (notification.Request.Cookies[portalUrlCookie] != null)
            {
                string portalUrl = notification.Request.Cookies[portalUrlCookie];
                int pos = portalUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
                string locale = portalUrl.Substring(pos, portalUrl.Length - pos);
                language = locale.Split('-')?[0];
            }
            string refererUrl = notification.Request.Headers["referer"];
            string country = refererUrl.Split('/')[3];
            string langPrefCookie = string.Format(langPrefCookieFormat, country);
            if (notification.Request.Cookies[langPrefCookie] != null)
            {
                string prefLang = notification.Request.Cookies[langPrefCookie].Split('-')[0];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefLang))
                {
                    language = prefLang;
                }
                else
                {
                    language = refererUrl.Split('/')[4].Split('-')[0];
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
                notification.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("ui_locales", language);
            Log.Info("End AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> AddLanguageQueryString", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

        }
        private static Task HandleOpenIdConnectAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context, OpenIdConnectSiteInfo site)
        {
            Log.Info("Start AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> HandleOpenIdConnectAuthenticationFailed", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

            if (context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
            }
            else
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                Log.Fatal(context.Exception.Message, context.Exception, typeof(OpenIdConnectAuthentication));
                UrlString errorUrl = new UrlString(site.ErrorUri);
                errorUrl.Add("message", context.Exception.Message);
                context.Response.Redirect(errorUrl.ToString());
            }
            Log.Info("End AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor -> HandleOpenIdConnectAuthenticationFailed", typeof(AzureAdB2CIdentityProviderProcessor));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Update 1
In the logs I am getting below error -

```
ERROR Unable to find "idp" claim in the identity. Make sure that "Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform" or analogue is used in claim transformations of all identity providers.
```

Tried adding below transformation in config, but still no luck.

```
 <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
```

Comment: Try restarting your CD instance and check your redirect url

Comment: @MaheshRaghupathi Thank you for your comment. Right now I am working on local, so cm and cd are same only. Restarting now.

Comment: @MaheshRaghupathi still getting the same error

Comment: In the posted code the call to apply the transformations (`ApplyClaimsTransformations`) is commented out, you still get the error in log if you uncomment that?

Comment: @Jeroen thank you for your comment. yes, i have uncommented it. still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer to below stackexchange question for working code - [Federated Authentication with Azure AD - Sitecore 9.3 - .Aspnet .Cookies not getting created](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29944/federated-authentication-with-azure-ad-sitecore-9-3-aspnet-cookies-not-get)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your approach is wrong. I once tried something similar, and using `args.App.MapWhen` directly is not supported as per Sitecore support, see more [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/29694/2495). This is how I have seen this work:

1. Remove the `args.App.MapWhen` and use same
   `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` for each site
2. Inside the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` set the correct OIDC options for the site, an example of this can be found in [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26865/2-sxa-sites-on-same-azure-app-service-need-different-federated-authentication-pr/26878#26878) answer. In case there are any settings which are not available here then you are probably in an area which is not supported by Sitecore Federated Authentication.

Comment: Hi @jeroen Thank you for your answer. I changed the code as per your answer but still getting the same error.

Comment: You able to post your updated code and config?